# Covariance function of the square of a Gaussian process

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, normal-distribution, covariance, gaussian

Let $X_t$, $t\in\mathbb{R}$, be a Gaussian process with mean $0$. Prove that $$
Cov(X_s^2,X_t^2)=2Cov(X_s,X_t)^2
$$

I don't know how to handle the squares here.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: You can represent to correlated standard normals $X_1, X_2$ as $X_1$ and $X_2 = \rho X_1 + \sqrt{1-\rho^2}Z$, where $Z$ is standard normal. Try to see what happens in that case and then generalize to arbitrary variances.

Comment: Just apply the definitions. You need $E(X_s^2 X_t^2)$, for which you can use conditional expectations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\sigma_s^2$ and $\sigma_t^2$ be the respective variances of $X_s$ and $X_t$, and let $\rho_{s,t}$ be their correlation. Then if $Z$ is standard normal and independent of $X_s$, we can redefine $X_t$ as
$$X_t/\sigma_t \overset{d}{=} \rho_{s,t} X_s/\sigma_s + \sqrt{1-\rho_{s,t}^2} Z$$
without changing the joint bivariate normal distribution $(X_s, X_t)$.

We have $E[X_s^2] = \sigma_s^4$ and $E[X_t^2] = \sigma_t^4$. Also,
\begin{align}
E[X_s^2 X_t^2]
&= E[X_s^2 \sigma_t^2 (\rho_{s,t} X_s/\sigma_s + \sqrt{1-\rho_{s,t}^2} Z)^2]
\\
&= \sigma_t^2 \rho_{s,t}^2 E[X_s^4]/ \sigma_s^2
+ 0 + \sigma_t^2 (1-\rho^2_{s,t}) E[X_s^2]E[Z^2]
\\
&= 3\sigma_s^2 \sigma_t^2 \rho^2_{s,t} + \sigma_s^2 \sigma_t^2 (1-\rho^2_{s,t})
\\
&= \sigma_s^2 \sigma_t^2 (2\rho_{s,t}^2 + 1).
\end{align}
So $\text{Cov}(X_s^2, X_t^2) = E[X_s^2 X_t^2] - E[X_s^2]E[X_t^2] = 2\sigma_s^2 \sigma_t^2 \rho^2_{s,t} = 2 \text{Cov}(X_s, X_t)^2$.

Comment: The result I need here is Theorem 5.3 in the book: https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter5/5_3_2_bivariate_normal_dist.php